# Where can I find information on local legal poker tournaments

Tags: live, tournament

I just found out that there are some relatively nearby casinos that host some low entry tourneys (<=$200 buy in)  Is there a site that has a relatively comprehensive listing of these tourneys?  If not how do people find out about them other than word of mouth?

Comment: Don't forget to chat with players while your at the Casino (be respectful of the game in progress, obviously). It's a great way to find out about games in the area.

Answer (score 6):

Your best source of information will be the casinos themselves.  Most casinos have web sites, and many of those include tournament schedules for their poker rooms.  Otherwise, you can call them, and they can tell you of any upcoming events.

Ante Up Magazine's web site has an [index of poker rooms by state](http://www.anteupmagazine.com/where-to-play/live-poker-rooms/) that could be of use in your search for nearby casinos.

Comment: TY for the poker room link that is great.